# Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'Google_Auth_Exception' with message 'Error fetching OAuth2 access token, message: 'invalid_client''

Tags: php, google-api, google-api-php-client

I am developing a mobile application with googleplus login. where I get the access token and send it to my server in order to verify it using [Google APIs Client Library for PHP](https://github.com/google/google-api-php-client).

When I try to authenticate the token I got a **Fatal Error Saying :**

```
Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'Google_Auth_Exception' with message 'Error fetching OAuth2 access token, message: 'invalid_client'' in C:\xxx\vendor\google\apiclient\src\Google\Auth\OAuth2.php:127 Stack trace: #0 C:\xxx\vendor\google\apiclient\src\Google\Client.php(130): Google_Auth_OAuth2->authenticate('ya29.2QBihTdAag...') #1 C:\xxx\index.php(20): Google_Client->authenticate('ya29.2QBihTdAag...') #2 {main} thrown in C:\xxx\vendor\google\apiclient\src\Google\Auth\OAuth2.php on line 127
```

and here is my PHP code:

```
<?php
    $google_client_id       = 'XXXXX.apps.googleusercontent.com';
    $google_client_secret   = 'XXXXX';
    $google_redirect_url    = 'xxx';
    $google_developer_key   = 'XXXXXXXX';
    $google_application_name = 'XXXX Login';
    $google_application_scope = 'email'; /* I only needed the basic user info */
    $google_redirect_uri='';
    //include google api files
    require_once 'vendor/autoload.php';

    $gClient = new Google_Client();
    $gClient->setApplicationName($google_application_name);
    $gClient->setClientId($google_client_id);
    $gClient->setClientSecret($google_client_secret);
    $gClient->setRedirectUri($google_redirect_uri);
    $gClient->setScopes($google_application_scope);
    $gClient->setDeveloperKey($google_developer_key);

    $gClient->authenticate("ya29.2QBihTdAagwpH5hHJUg5soIETLspVUgle6VPOT52UYPWkOKyHdUJlpUyvoMKPgkuqIS4PvgXQhfpHw");//Error Happened here
    $token = json_decode($gClient->getAccessToken());

    $google_oauthV2 = new Google_Service_Oauth2($gClient);
   $user_info = $google_oauthV2->userinfo->get();
   var_dump(user_info);
   die();  
    ?>
```

Comment: did your client id and secret key is correct?

Comment: @Anju, I am using clinet ID and secret of "Client ID for web application " and not of "Client ID for Android application ".

Comment: did you followed these steps http://www.smarttutorials.net/login-with-google-oauth-2-using-php-and-mysql/ . Double check the client is and secret key, there is no space in starting and ending

Comment: @Anju thank, but I am sending the token from android application, and not from the browser

Comment: I am on the same error. It has something to do with the token. Android call 'GoogleAuthUtil.getToken' returns just some portion of the access token string or something.' direct getInfo call works. I am investigating.

Answer (score -1):

For `$google_client_secret`, instead of `'notasecret'` use the value in the `"CLIENT SECRET"` section of your `"Client ID for web application"`.